# How to use line break as the separator?

Tags: python, input

So, in python's program, there is console input looks like :

```
Word1
Word2
Word3
```

I want to put this input to list, and have every line break as separator of one item from another. So, after program got this input in console, the list value should be like: `["Word1", "Word2", "Word3"]`

How can I make it so? 
Thank you!

Comment: "there is console input", if you're using the built-in function `input`, it's already separated at newlines. Can you specify how you read this?

Comment: if thats console input then how are you getting it? are you using `input()`

Comment: Console input ends when the Enter key is pressed, so you can't have console input like you describe.

Comment: Yes. I'm using python's "input()" function as the source of information. So, user type values in console using line break, and this very line break separate array's elements one out of other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using `input()` as the means of getting the values since you say that is "console input". This can be done using a list comprehension such as below:

```
data = [input() for i in range(3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
s = "Word1\nWord2\nWord3"
splitted = s.split()
print(splitted)
```